# How can I "intercept" a method call for a test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class like so:

```
class A {

    public static void makeCall() {
        URL url = "www.google.com";
        InputStream result = url.openStream();
        //Do more stuff
    }
}
```

And I want to write a unit test for it. What I want to happen is sort of "intercept" the call to `openStream()` so that I can run the static method `makeCall()` and just return some sort of hard coded JSON back, instead of actually making the call. I haven't been able to figure out how to mock this up, or if it's even possible.

I am looking for the same behavior as Angular's `$httpBackend`, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You should probably separate out the HTTP code from the logic you're actually trying to test (think dependency injection).

Comment: So you're thinking separate the call into something like `makeHTTPCall(URL url)` and then just mock that method to return the JSON? That could definitely work

Comment: If you really must mock it, it's trivial to do with the JMockit mocking library (declare a `@Mocked URL url` mock field then record the desired expectation on `openStream()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to mock method member variables. For better design make the url a parameter in the method.

```
public static void makeCall(URL url){
```

Then in your test pass in a mock.

This also allows for more flexibility and possible code reuse in the future.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Made it easily mockable and the design felt better.